# Failed To execute goal org.jenkins-ci.tools:maven-hpi-plug in:3.11:resolve-test-dependencies(default-cli)

Tags: maven, jenkins, prometheus

I am unable to build jenkins prometheus-plugin code base at my local.

Getting following error on executing `mvn clean install`:

```
**Failed To execute goal org.jenkins-ci.tools:maven-hpi-plug in:3.11:resolve-test-dependencies(default-cli) on project prometheus**

**Failed to resolve : org.jenkins-ci.plugins.pipeline-stage-view:pipeline-rest-api:hpi:2.6**
```

I tried installing this `org.jenkins-ci.plugins.pipeline-stage-view:pipeline-rest-api:hpi:2.6` manually still no luck.

please help/suggest what I need to do to execute this goal.

Any help would be great.